# Por que me dice que el parámetro de salida no esta asignado?

Tags: c#

Tengo un método operaciones que tiene un parámetro de salida, mediante un switch determina que tipo de operación va a realizar y dar valor a `resultado` y al final del switch pongo un return para que mande el parámetro de salida pero me marca que el parámetro esta sin asignar

```
     public double Operaciones(out double resultado)
    {
        switch (tipoOperacion)
        {
            case 0: resultado = x + y; break;
            case 1: resultado = x - y; break;
            case 2: resultado = x / y; break;
            case 3: resultado = x * y; break;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: te falta el default

Answer (score 0):

Te informa que está "sin asignar" porque en tu definición del parámetro no envías un valor.
Podrías colocar un [valor por default](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)
Ejemplo
...double Operaciones(out double resultado = 0)

(Dale una mirada porque no en tu código no sabemos de dónde viene la variable tipoOperacion y si puede tener otros valores que no están contemplados en el switch, lo recomendable aquí es que utilices alguna enumeración si amerita ese tipo de.valores)

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guía

- [Argumentos opcionales y con nombre (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)